# How can you create a c# dependent variable?

Tags: c#, webforms

I am trying to create a c# method that can be reused multiple times,but depending on the condition of the variable type, i would like to be able to construct the name of a text field.

For example, if type="TY" then I would like to call

```
if ((String)this.TYIdlabelChange.Value == null)
```

However, if type="CA", then I would like to call

```
if ((String)this.CAIdlabelChange.Value == null)
```

Other examples:

```
if ((String)this.DIIdlabelChange.Value == null)
if ((String)this.LOIdlabelChange.Value == null)
if ((String)this.REIdlabelChange.Value == null)
etc...
```

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: what is `this`? and what is `this.TYIdlabelChange`?

Comment: Use an if() statement or Reflection or a Dictionary<> or the collection these labels are stored in.

Comment: What is the type of `TYIdlabelChange` and et all?

Comment: @Grundy it is how I am accessing the text boxes on my page

Comment: so you use webform? and `this` is `Page`?

Comment: when you say type="TY", type of what?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Textfield

Comment: @ErenErsönmez it is just a reference to the id of the text box

Comment: @Grundy exactly! well its actually webform1 but yes

Comment: if you want to check the type of an object use can use `is` keyword: `if(this is TY){ if ((String)(this as TY).TYIdlabelChange.Value == null) }`

Comment: possibly you need [`(FindControl(type+"IdLabelChange") as Textbox).Value == null`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/31hxzsdw(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @user3397607 I don't think the question is very clear, and I doubt you will get any good answers. You should write a more complete code example demonstrating your problem and refer only to the code in your example. Statements like type=TY doesn't make any sense because we can't understand the context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need use [Page.FindControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/31hxzsdw(v=vs.110).aspx), something like this

```
var tb = FindControl(type+"IdlabelChange") as Textbox;
if(tb != null && tb.Value != null){
    ....
}
```